# Find visible plugins with multiple templates and static placeholders

Tags: django, django-cms

is there any way to check if a Plugin is visible (published) anywhere in a page?
I have multiple pages with different templates each. 
These templates have different static placeholders which have different plugins.

The problem is some plugins are present on templates which are not activated and therefore I don't want to get those in my query.

Is there a method to show only the plugins which are visible on the published pages?
Same question: Is there a method to show only the plugins which appear on the activated templates?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I want to do this because I am trying to fill a search database i.e. index.

Comment: It's django-cms terminology. I want to index data for the search engine, but showing data in search results,  which is not in displayed on the (web)sites - pages, is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method on the `Page` model called `is_published`;

```
def is_published(self, language, force_reload=False):
    return self.get_title_obj(language, False, force_reload=force_reload).published
```

And you can find the page any given `CMSPlugin` object is attached to through it's placeholder.

So on a filter of your plugin you could do;

```
draft_objects = MyPlugin.objects.filter(placeholder__page__publisher_is_draft=True)
live_objects = MyPlugin.objects.filter(placeholder__page__publisher_is_draft=False)
```

As a further example, I have an image gallery plugin added via a 'gallery' placeholder. Each gallery detail view offers links to other image galleries that are associated with the same page;

```
# Filter the list of other galleries so that we don't get galleries
# attached to other pages.
more_galleries = [
    g for g in galleries if (
        g.placeholder.slot == u'gallery' and
        unicode(g.placeholder.page.id) == page_id
    )
]
```

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'activated templates' but if you mean templates that are in use on a page, you'd have to filter the pages for a given template name first before filtering your plugins based on the pages. Sounds complicated (big SQL queries) & you'd need to explain what/why you're wanting that.

*edit*

If it's search you want - check out [Aldryn Search](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-search) which is a search app written by the django CMS devs.